# Div heights are different between 2 webpages but coded the same

Tags: css, height, html

I have 3 webpages. The first is called inventorshome, second PythonTutorialHome, third HTMLTutorialHome. The second and third look the same in the browser. Notice that the code is exactly the same for the pages. They should look exactly the same by that logic. For some reason, the div is larger for inventorshome than in PythonTutorialHome and HTMLTutorialHome. I am using Google Chrome browser, and they are files on my computer.

Here is the code for inventorshome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <title>Home</title>
            <base href="file:///C:/Users/David/Documents/Website/Pages/">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/David/Documents/Website/Pages/inventorshomestyles.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="header">
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Here is the code for PythonTutorialHome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <base href="file:///C:/Users/David/Documents/Website/Pages/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/David/Documents/Website/Pages/inventorshomestyles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS linked to these webpages is:

```
#header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background-color:#8AC007;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    }
```

When I change the width and height to percentages, they are the same across all three pages. When the dimensions to pixels, different results are yielded. What is going on here?

Comment: Is there any other code which might be affecting the behaviour?

Comment: There is no other code. I just tested it again and found the source of the problem. Google Chrome saved the zoom for the inventorshome page at 110% because I bookmarked the page. While the PythonTutorialHome page was saved at 100%. So even if I exited out of the page, and opened it again, it would have a 110% zoom. Sometimes the environment can cause issues.